# How to use taglib with uri?

Tags: jsp, jstl, taglib

I want to use jstl and I put this at the top of my page:

`<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>`

I have added jstl.jar and standard.jar in my library. I also put them in /webapp/WEB-INF/lib. The two jars come from the example in Tomcat.

My IDE is myeclipse, my server is Tomcat 8.0, jsp version is 3.0.

When I run my page I have an exception with:

`type: Exception report`

`message: /TestPerson.jsp (line: 2, column: 62) File "file:/C:/Program%20Files/Apache%20Software%20Foundation/Tomcat%208.0/webapps/Beer-v1/WEB-INF/tld/c.tld" not found`

`description: The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.`

But I have the c.tld in the filepath above!

How can I deal with that!

Comment: So.. You extracted the JAR's contents and cluttered the `/WEB-INF` with loose tld files? And you possibly also added them to the `web.xml`? Why? In any case .. Put your mouse on top of `[jstl]` tag which you correctly placed on the question until a black box shows up and then click therein the *info* link.

Comment: By the way, please try to find more recent JSP books/tutorials/resources. The decade-old Beer webapp example is still from JSP 1.x era and therefore hopelessly outdated and according the current standards basically only teaching bad practices.

Comment: Thanks! I should not add the .tld files in my web apps. Use the JSTL 1.2.1 can solve my problem!